# How to make IntelliJ IDEA recognize build-time generated sources?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, compilation, auto-generate, auto-value

I made a [small zip example](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8sd7icgq98gcwc1/AAAUBPfkQFkwRM53qE98yYH5a?dl=0) to illustrate the issue.

I have in the project the Animal class from [AutoValue example](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md) and a maven pom file to do the code generation and compilation. See below.

Running `mvn clean install` works great and generates and compiles everything into `target/classes`:

[image]

The problem is that IntelliJ doesn't recognize `AutoValue_Animal`:

[image]

**So how to make IntelliJ IDEA recognize build-time generated sources?**

* Preferably, without needing to change IDEA specific setting, in order to keep the dev env consolidated around Maven.

**Class:**

```
package kilaka;

import com.google.auto.value.AutoValue;

@AutoValue
public abstract class Animal {
    static Animal create(String name, int numberOfLegs) {
        // See "How do I...?" below for nested classes.
        return new AutoValue_Animal(name, numberOfLegs);
    }

    abstract String name();

    abstract int numberOfLegs();
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>kilaka</groupId>
    <artifactId>auto-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-value</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Maven conventions (recognized by IntelliJ) would place generated sources in `target/generated-sources/[plugin-name]`.

Comment: @Tome So who's placing the generated java file into `target/classes`?

Comment: Usually it is the process/plugin actually doing the generation. Here, as the `com.google.auto.value:auto-value` is rather an APT than an external plugin, you can have a look here: https://immutables.github.io/apt.html

Comment: @Tome `auto-value` isn't a plugin. It's a dependency. Anyhow, It's maven that is putting the generated content in `target/classes`. Not IntelliJ.

Comment: Yes, it is rather an annotation processor, and the compiler plugin should place the generated sources in ` ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations` (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html)

Comment: @Tome using `generatedSourcesDirectory` solved the issue. Thank you. Do you want to add an answer or will I?

Comment: Go ahead with the answer, glad it helped.

Comment: It seems that the fix eventually was to use the `source` tag in `maven-compiler-plugin`. Didn't matter whether the source is `5` or `8`.

Comment: Enable annotation processing in Intellij Preferences so that while building code will compile and run test.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that worked for me but don't like it. I unmarked the `target` folder from `Excluded` and marked the `classes` as `Sources`.

In order to continue excluding all other target folders, I had to mark all other folders as excluded.

[image]

This is a **bad** solution because:

1. If you want to keep your code clean from dev-env, you aren't committing IDEA'a configuration files. Thus need to repeat this step on every clone.
2. If additional folders are starting to get into the `target` folder, you need to manually exclude them.
3. The solution is not maven centric, causing dev-env configuration to be split into several files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following fixes the issue:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>6</source>
        <target>6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This caused the file `AutoValue_Animal.java` to be generated in `target/generated-sources/annotations`, which IntelliJ IDEA read without any additional tweaking.

I read that annotation processing wasn't supported in Java 5 (yet the class was generated). See more info [here](https://github.com/google/auto/issues/482#issuecomment-297711192).

Comment: See explanation in https://github.com/google/auto/issues/482#issuecomment-297711192

Comment: _“I read that annotation processing wasn't supported in Java 5 (yet the class was generated)”_ Because you're not using Java 5, you're (probably) using Java 7 or 8 and telling it to cross-compile for a Java 5-compatible runtime (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html#BHCIJIEG); this is not the same! And beware that this could break at runtime given you're not passing a `-bootclasspath`: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/beware-sirens-target-call